# generating a sum coding scheme

Tags: r, encoding

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id= rep(seq(1:125),3),
  timpoint= c(rep("T1", 125), rep("T2", 125), rep("T3", 125)),
                 treatment=c(rep("A",25),rep("B",25),rep("C",25),rep("D",25),rep("E",25)))
interaction.col <- paste(df$timpoint, df$treatment, sep = "_")  

df <- cbind(df, interaction.col)
```

I am trying to generate a sum coding scheme for the interaction column which is a combination of the first two columns. According to [this](https://onlinelibrary-wiley-com.vu-nl.idm.oclc.org/doi/full/10.1002/cem.2895) paper I should get a matrix of (a−1)×(b−1) columns and n rows(in this case 375)

I have read up on using contrasts:

```
 contrasts(df$interaction.col) <-  "contr.sum"
     df.c <- contrasts(df$interaction.col)
```

However, somehow the output is a 15x14 matrix, while it should be a 375 x8.
Also, only the very last row is set to -1, which shouldn't be the case.  For all the ID's of the last treatment (E) the interaction column should be set to -1 for the corresponding timepoint.
The last ID in treatment group E should be -1 for all columns. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what effects you are interested in and how you will fit the model, you will end up with different number of effects. For example, in the case whereby you fit the main and interaction effects, you should end up with 8 columns for the interactions ie (a-1) x (b-1). In the case you do not fit the main effects you end up with a*b - 1:

Here is how to create your matrix:

### With main effects:

```
model.matrix(~treatment * timpoint, df, list(treatment = contr.sum, timpoint=contr.sum))
```

In this case, the last 8 columns are the ones you are interested in

### Without main effects:

```
model.matrix(~treatment:timpoint, df, list(treatment = contr.sum, timpoint=contr.sum))
```

Comment: This almost gives the desired matrix, I was under the assumption that when sum-coding is used the rows for the last level would be -1 instead of 1. I can easily fix this offcourse  by simply subsetting the rows and multiply it with -1, but its just out of curiosity that I'd like to know why the last level is not set tot -1.

Comment: @Hedayat the contrast matrix has the last row being equal to -1. And the sum of the colums for the contrast matrix will be zero. There is a difference between the contrast matrix and the model matrix. In your case here, it seems you asked for the model matrix and not the contrast matrix. Since there are two factors you should get two contrast matrices, 1 with 5×4 and the other with 3×2. Also note that there will be -1s in your model matrix, but not necessarily the last row. You need to learn more about contrast matrices and model matrices. Ogherwise this is the correct answer to your problem

Comment: This has been a thorne in my sight, but I can't seem to solve the issue for changing the base for the  interaction effects. I tried relevel but this doesn't give any results